# SavedModel file does not exist at: model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

> **Tensorflow Version 2.0 Tried in Colab as Well as local**
>
> **Ubuntu 18.4**
>
> model.h5 is in current working directry

```
import tensorflow as tf

export_dir='model.h5'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

> Output

```
SavedModel file does not exist at: model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Comment: is your model a keras model?

Comment: yes it is Keras model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is a keras model, you have to load it using `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(export_dir)` instead of `from_saved_model`. As written [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#converting_a_keras_model_).

Also, make sure, the file is accessible via your defined path `export_dir`.

Comment: It creates an `AttributeError` `type object 'TFLiteConverter' has no attribute 'from_keras_model`

Comment: What is your TF version?